# Life support system weight estimate

Tags: life-support, eclss

I would need to estimate the weight of the life support system, specifically the weight of the oxygen subsystem. Are there weights for previous spacecraft available somewhere? Or is some other procedure used to estimate the weight?

Answer (score 8):

NASA has developed a tool for sizing ECLSS systems called ALSSAT (Advanced Life Support Sizing Analysis Tool).

There is a fairly detailed description available to read in the paper [ALSSAT Development Status and Its Applications in Trade Studies](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20150020426/downloads/20150020426.pdf)

[image]

The tool is available to the general public through the NASA Tech Transfer Program [here](https://software.nasa.gov/software/MSC-25510-1). (Registration may be required)

Comment: Thank you, but it says that the progarm is US relase only. I am from Europe. What should I do?

Comment: @SaturnV Sorry, your question did not specify and I have no idea how or wish to circumvent the restrictions. Perhaps the answer can help others in the future.

Comment: So there is no way to get it?

Comment: @SaturnV you could try writing NASA and asking.

Comment: @SaturnV you're from Europe? maybe ESA has a concept. If not, you might be out of luck. Other than ESA, NASA's going to be your best bet.

Comment: Yes, I am from ESA member state. How should I ask them?